# Why am I getting a syntax error using SQL pivot?

Tags: sql, pivot

I'm getting a syntax error at 1 JAN.

My SampleStart is in datetime format. Am I aliasing something wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT year(SampleStart) year, month(SampleStart) month, AllowedPopulation
  FROM BIC_AGGREGATE_FINAL
  WHERE SampleStart BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
) as s
PIVOT (
  max(AllowedPopulation) 
  FOR month in (
    1 JAN, 2 FEB, 3 MAR, 4 APR, 5 MAY, 6 JUN,
    7 JUL, 8 AUG, 9 SEP, 10 OCT, 11 NOV, 12 DEC
  )
)
ORDER BY year DESC
```

I'm expecting the results to show me the allowed population for each month in the year 2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot supply your column aliases within the pivot function, you have to do this in the select. Also, when specifying your `IN` clause within the pivot you must apply similar rules to when selecting columns, if the column is a reserved word, or contains special characters (e.g. space), or starts with a number etc then you must enclose the name in square brackets.

Finally, you have to give the pivot function itself an alias.

e.g.

```
SELECT  pvt.[year],
        JAN = pvt.[1],
        FEB = pvt.[2],
        MAR = pvt.[3],
        APR = pvt.[4],
        MAY = pvt.[5],
        JUN = pvt.[6],
        JUL = pvt.[7],
        AUG = pvt.[8],
        SEP = pvt.[9],
        OCT = pvt.[10],
        NOV = pvt.[11],
        DEC = pvt.[12]
FROM (
  SELECT YEAR(SampleStart) AS [year], MONTH(SampleStart) AS [month], AllowedPopulation
  FROM BIC_AGGREGATE_FINAL
  WHERE SampleStart BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
) AS s
PIVOT (
  MAX(AllowedPopulation) 
  FOR month IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]) 
) AS pvt -- Alias here too
ORDER BY pvt.[year] DESC
```

If, as the question states `SampleStart` is a `DATETIME` column, then I would make two changes to your where clause:

1. Use a exclusive date range instead of `BETWEEN` - [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
2. Use the unambiguous date literal format `yyyyMMdd`, depending on your settings `2018-10-01` could either be 10th January, or 1st October.

So you would end up with:

```
   WHERE SampleStart >= '20180101' 
   AND SampleStart < '20190101'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with-

```
SELECT  year,
[1] AS JAN,
[2] AS FEB,
[3] AS MAR,
[4] AS APR,
[5] AS MAY,
[6] AS JUN,
[7] AS JUL,
[8] AS AUG,
[9] AS SEP,
[10] AS OCT,
[11] AS NOV,
[12] AS DEC


FROM 
(
    SELECT year(SampleStart) year, 
    month(SampleStart) month, 
    AllowedPopulation
    FROM BIC_AGGREGATE_FINAL
    WHERE SampleStart BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
) as s
PIVOT 
(
max(AllowedPopulation) 
FOR month in (
    [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6],
    [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]
)
)AS PVT
ORDER BY year DESC
```